# Encryption key to view realm file on Mac using Realm browser

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using Realm for my android application, I want to view the default.realm file on my mac using Realm browser, however it is asking for an encryption key.
[image]
I am not doing encryption in the Realm Configuration explicitly by providing ".encryptionKey(key)". Then what encryption key do I have to provide? Is there any encryption by default? I am using Realm plugin 2.0.2 on Android Studio and my Realm Browser is 2.0.1 on mac.
I have also tried to provide an encryptionKey(key) like this in my code:

```
byte[] key = new byte[64];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(key);
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
.encryptionKey(key)
.build();
```

And tried to supply the same hash(128 length) to the browser to open the file ,but no Luck. I have found answers in SO related to how to retrieve the file using adb pull, but I am clueless about this encryption part. Any help in this regard would be great.

Comment: It sounds like your Realm file is damaged. Did you copy the file while it was open?

Comment: I copied the file while I had connected my phone to my mac and was debugging via Android Studio. I used this command to copy the file contents as my phone was not rooted.
    ./adb shell "run-as <package-name> cat /data/data/<package-name>/files/default.realm" > ~/default.realm

Comment: Thanks @geisshirt for the tip. I was thinking it was encrypted the whole time. With you advice I understood that it was because of corruption.

Answer (score 5):

Well the issue was that the file was corrupted. The error message from Realm browser was rather misleading asking for an encryption key.

Since my phone wasn't rooted, I was not able to retrieve the file directly using adb pull.

```
adb pull /data/data/<packagename>/files/ .
```

I was using another command by copying the contents to a file on my system, which lead to the corruption.

Here is the command which finally worked for me.

```
./adb exec-out run-as <packagename> cat /data/data/<packagename>/files/default.realm > ~/Documents/foo/foo.realm
```

I didn't put the exec-out in the command before, which was the reason for corruption.